# convergence of complex series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Set that Re $z_n>=0$,$\forall$ n $\in$ N,Proof that if $\sum z_n$ and $\sum {z_n}^2$ are both convergent,then $\sum |z_n|^2$ is also convergent.
Well I've no idea how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Putting $\,z_n:=x_n+iy_n\;,\;\;x_n,y_n\in\Bbb R\,$ we have that

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n\;\;\text{converges}\,\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\;,\;\; \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n\;\;\text{both converge}$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n^2\,\,\text{converges}\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(x_n^2-y_n^2\right)\;,\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n \;\;\text{all converge}$$

Further hint: with the usual topologies on $\,\Bbb R\,,\,\Bbb C\,$, a complex sequence converges iff both the sequences of its real and imaginary parts converge.